Lack of strong law for triangular array
Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in the natural numbers with
$$
\operatorname{P}\left(X = n\right) =
{1 \over \zeta(3)\,n^{3}}
$$
where $\zeta(3) := \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}1/n^{2}$ ( this is an example of a Zeta Distribution ):

Let ${(X_{i,n})_{i,n \in {\bf N}: 1 \leq i \leq n}}$ be jointly independent copies of ${X}$.
Show that the random variables
$$
{\frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{n,n}}{n}}
$$
are almost surely unbounded. ( Hint: for any constant ${A}$, show that $\left(X_{1,n} + \cdots +X_{n,n}\right)/n > A$ occurs with probability at least ${\varepsilon/n}$ for some ${\varepsilon > 0}$ depending on  ${A}$. Then use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma. Start for instance with the events $X_{in} > nA$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ ).

Question:

By approximating form below by an integral, one can show that ${\bf P}(X_{i,n} > nA) \geq 1/\left[2\zeta(3)(nA)^2\right] = \varepsilon/n^{2}, \varepsilon = 1/\left[2\zeta(3)A^2\right]$.
But then it is unclear how to derive the bound for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i,n} > A$ to be $\varepsilon/n$ as in the hint, some further hint are appreciated.


You're essentially being asked to approximate the tail of the sum. For any fixed $k$ and sufficiently large $t$, it turns out in this case that
$$\mathbf{P}\Bigl[\sum_{i=1}^k X_i > t\Bigr] \approx k \mathbf{P}[X > t].$$
That is, if the sum is giant, it is most likely because one of the terms is giant. (This is a classic property of heavy-tailed distributions.)
Because you only need a lower bound, you can start with
$$\mathbf{P}\Bigl[\sum_{i=1}^k X_i > t\Bigr] \geq \mathbf{P}\Bigl[\max_{i\in\{1\,\dots,k\}} X_i > t\Bigr],$$
because the max might be easier to work with. Specifically, the principle of inclusion-exclusion can help you work with the max.

Thanks for the feedback. This is a nice heuristic to have at the back of mind when dealing with tail probability of sum of this kind. As subadditivity will give an upper rather than a lower bound, can you provide (or give some reference to) a slightly more rigorous justification for this fact?

Indeed, it's clear that $\mathbf{P}[\max_i X_i > t] \leq k \mathbf{P}[X > t]$, so your job is to show that there's a lower bound that's similar as $t \to \infty$. Try using the inclusion–exclusion principle (or it's truncated version, the Bonferroni inequality).

It occurs to me that a binomial approximation would suffice in this case. But anyway thanks for your explanation.

For verification purpose I'll also post a complete solution here.
For any constant $A > 0$, consider the events $X_{i,n} > nA$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$. By definition, we have
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(X_{i,n} > nA) = \sum_{j \geq \lceil{nA}\rceil} \frac{1}{\zeta(3)} \frac{1}{j^3} \geq \frac{1}{\zeta(3)} \int_{\lceil{nA}\rceil}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3}\ dx \geq \frac{1}{\zeta(3)} \frac{1}{2(nA + 1)^2} \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{n^2}$,
for some $\varepsilon > 0$ depending on $A$.
Denote the sum of row $n$ by $S_n$, it follows that
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(S_n > nA) \geq {\bf P}(\bigvee_{i=1}^n (X_{i,n} > nA)) = 1 - {\bf P}(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n (X_{i,n} \leq nA)) \geq 1 - (1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{n^2})^n$.
From binomial approximation, $\displaystyle (1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{n^2})^n \approx 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{n}$ (with the error term absorbed into the $\varepsilon$ term), thus we have $\displaystyle {\bf P}(S_n > nA) \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{n}$ for some $\varepsilon = \varepsilon(A)$. As the $\varepsilon / n$ are not summable in $n$, the second Borel-Cantelli lemma implies that almost surely an infinite number of the events $S_n/n > A$ holds simultaneously, i.e. the row averages are almost surely unbounded.
